# CPU% Cost Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cpu

SQL Server execution plans show an "Estimated CPU Cost" in the operator properties and tooltips as in the following example

[image: enter link description here]

Does this "Estimated CPU Cost" represent the estimated "CPU usage %" (as shown in tools like task manager or perfmon?)

Comment: Very generic, `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`, please eloberate your question with sample data or execution plan.

Comment: @BHouse no need for any of that information to answer this question as it is a factual question about what the meaning of some standard information shown in execution plans is. This meaning does not vary per query.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the "Estimated CPU Cost" shown in the execution plan represent
>   the estimated CPU usage %

No this number is a unitless number that is generated by the cost model. When added to the IO Cost and other fixed per operator cost this gets an overall plan cost that originally (last millennium) was somewhat correlated with execution time in seconds on a [certain Microsoft employees machine](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dannyr/2008/10/09/what-estimated-subtree-cost-1-means-or-a-great-sql-server-history-story/)

[image: enter link description here]

These days it can not be correlated with any specific estimate of CPU utilisation as a percent or in elapsed time and is only intended to be used by the optimiser itself when costing plans and comparing plan costs.

You can see that this has no real world correlation as the CPU costs for the same operator will be largely the same across computers running the same version of SQL Server irrespective of the model of CPU that they contain (and many of the formulas have remained much the same across multiple product versions since SQL Server 2000)

E.g. Joe Chang [calculated](http://studylib.net/doc/5634648/sql-server-query-optimizer-cost-formulas) that a Clustered Index Scan, Table Scan, Index Seek Will be given a CPU Cost of `0.0001581` +  `0.0000011` per row.

You might also be interested in reading [Inside the Optimizer: Plan Costing](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/09/01/inside-the-optimizer-plan-costing.aspx)